# How to create the query to get correct result with pluralization?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This is my table I need to get results like:

```
in 560038 two hospitals, one temple, zero masjid, zero company, one church and 
in 560049 one schools, one masjid, one company, zero temple, zero hospitals, and 
in 562129 one high school, zero hospitals, zero company, zero masjid , zero temple. 

604=hospital,
1306=temple,
1302=church,
204=school,
1305=masjid,
102=company.
```

Is it possible to get from a single query in mysql? Here I can give city_id only.

```
id  |cat_id|poi_id |addr                    |pincode|city_id 
1   |6     |604     |Amrutha  Hospital      |560038 |284 
2   |13    |1306    |Temple             |560038 |284 
3   |13    |1302    |Resurrection Church    |560038 |284 
4   |2     |204     |Lake Montfort School   |560049 |284 
5   |6     |604     |Garden City Hospital   |560038 |284 
6   |13    |1305    |Bilal Masjid           |560049 |284 
7   |1     |102     |Grindwell Limited      |560049 |284 
8   |2     |204     |Citizen High School    |562129 |284
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expressions within `COUNT()` to conditionally aggregate `poi_id`s to differentiate the counts, grouped by `pincode`.

You want:

```
SELECT   pincode,
         COUNT(CASE poi_id WHEN 604  THEN 1 END) AS hospital_cnt,
         COUNT(CASE poi_id WHEN 1306 THEN 1 END) AS temple_cnt,
         COUNT(CASE poi_id WHEN 1302 THEN 1 END) AS church_cnt,
         COUNT(CASE poi_id WHEN 204  THEN 1 END) AS school_cnt,
         COUNT(CASE poi_id WHEN 1305 THEN 1 END) AS masjid_cnt,
         COUNT(CASE poi_id WHEN 102  THEN 1 END) AS company_cnt
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY pincode
```

**Edit:** As per your comments, you can get a row format of the counts of each possible `poi_id` per `pincode`:

```
SELECT     a.pincode,
           b.poi_id,
           COUNT(c.pincode) AS cnt
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT pincode FROM tbl) a
CROSS JOIN poi b
LEFT JOIN  tbl c ON a.pincode = c.pincode AND b.poi_id = c.poi_id
GROUP BY   a.pincode, b.poi_id
```

Where `poi` is the name of the table that `poi_id` links to. Make sure the column names are consistent too.

If you still want one row per `pincode`, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to bring the counts all into one delimited string:

```
SELECT   a.pincode,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.poi_id, ': ', a.cnt) SEPARATOR ' / ') AS poi_cnts
FROM     (
         SELECT     a.pincode,
                    b.poi_id,
                    COUNT(c.pincode) AS cnt
         FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT pincode FROM tbl) a
         CROSS JOIN poi b
         LEFT JOIN  tbl c ON a.pincode = c.pincode AND b.poi_id = c.poi_id
         GROUP BY   a.pincode, b.poi_id
         ) a
GROUP BY a.pincode
```

Comment: This will helps, but the problem is in this table i have more than 6500 rows are there , and poi_id's  are more than 1000.. i want to give poi_id also dynamically...

Comment: @Pramod, what table is `poi_id` linked to? We may be able to derive the counts in row format instead of column format.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't possible with a relational database.  A result set needs to have a fixed number of columns.

Comment: @ZaneBien great man!, Thanks a lot . It's works. but right now what is the problem is my table has more than 65000 rows because that query taking more time.. i need to do some thing for that.. any thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT pincode, poi_id, COUNT(1) AS place_cnt
FROM table_name
GROUP BY pincode, poi_id;
```

Comment: No, the results are not depending up on addr but on poi_id, because addr is unique.. from that i will get addr is school or masjid etec...

Comment: EDIT: change address to poi_id may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select pincode, addr, count(id) from YourTable group by pincode, addr
```

Comment: the addr is not important to me. For me i need to display number of temple , hospital ,masjid in a city ...

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood correctly, you want a resultset where each row is the pincode followed by the numver of each type of point of interest.

The target results you specified look like the need to be a long, natural english string. I'm not going to get you that far but I will give you something that you can work with in code.

Here's the end result that you'll end up with:

```
pincode | hospitals | temples | masjids | companies | churches | schools
560038  |     2     |    1    |    0    |     0     |    1     |    0
560049  |     0     |    0    |    1    |     1     |    0     |    1
562129  |     0     |    0    |    0    |     0     |    0     |    1
```

NOTE: I don't think requiring the results in this way is ideal.  If new types of points of interest are added later you'll have to rewrite the query. But since this is the question, here's the answer:

There's two ways to do this and both use sub queries that do count(*) for each type of point of interest.  The first option is the embed the sub queries in the SELECT part of the query.  The second option is to make derived tables out of the sub queries and join them together.

Here's option 1:

```
SELECT
mainTbl.pincode,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 604) as hospitals,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 1306) as temples,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 1305) as masjids,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 1302) as churches,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 204) as schools,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 102) as companies
FROM myTable mainTbl
WHERE mainTbl.city_id = ?
```

And option2:

```
SELECT
mainTbl.pincode,
hospitalsTbl.hospitals,
templesTbl.temples,
masjidsTbl.masjids,
churchesTbl.churches,
schoolsTbl.schools,
companiesTbl.companies

FROM myTable mainTbl
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as hospitals, pincode FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id  AND poi_id = 604) hospitalsTbl ON hospitalsTbl.pincode = mainTbl.pincode
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as temples, pincode FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 1306) templesTbl ON templesTbl.pincode = mainTbl.pincode
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as masjids, pincode FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 1305) masjidsTbl ON masjidsTbl.pincode = mainTbl.pincode
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as churches, pincode FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 1302) churchesTbl ON churchesTbl.pincode = mainTbl.pincode
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as schools, pincode FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 204) schoolsTbl ON schoolsTbl.pincode = mainTbl.pincode
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as companies, pincode FROM myTable WHERE pincode = mainTbl.pincode AND city_id = mainTbl.city_id AND poi_id = 102) companiesTbl ON companiesTbl.pincode = mainTbl.pincode
WHERE mainTbl.city_id = ?
```

As you can see the queries are quite verbose.  It's much better to have something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as num_poi, poi_id, pincode
FROM myTable
WHERE city_id = ?
GROUP BY poi_id, pincode
```

and then build your one line rows in code.

Comment: Ahh the chosen answer is way better than this tripe that I suggested!